# Remove <space><comma> but not <space><space><comma>

Tags: regex, string, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that has un-encapsulated text strings, some that contain commas.  This of course throws off the CSV parser.

My CSV has the following patterns:

- A column with no value will contain 2 spaces
- A column with a value will look like `<comma><value><comma>`, with no spaces between the value and the commas.

All of the errant commas that I need to remove (that are contained in text strings) are either preceded by or followed by a single space.  Example:

```
<somevalue,Check this out, I think you'll like it.,<somevalue>
```

I need to regex to replace that `<space><comma>` with just a `<space>` or a `<hyphen>`.  But I can't just search on comma> because that will catch all of the valid  instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<![ ])[ ],
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

Comment: I would use `[ ]` instead of ` ` just to be clear... and it works with `RegexOption.IgnoreWhitespace`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to match on non-space followed by space and comma and replace with the non-space:

```
... -replace '(^|[^ ]) ,', '$1'
```